# Slider In Proudect Page Per Ads

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, slider

Hello I Am Working On A Startup and I Have A Huge Problem In My Project.
In Searching Page User Can Search By Different Item And Ads Showed.
I Wanna Per Each Ad In The Picture Area Shows Picture By Slider. 
Let Me Show By Pic .
This Is Searching Page
[Searchin_Page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q2PVu.png)

I Wanna Use Slider For Each Ad That Shows But Its Dose not Work True . . . 
This Is My Jquery Code

```
var slideIndex = 1;
showDivs(slideIndex);

function plusDivs(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex += n);
}

function currentDiv(n) {
  showDivs(slideIndex = n);
}

function showDivs(n) {
  var i;
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
  var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("demo");
  if (n > x.length) {
    slideIndex = 1
  }
  if (n < 1) {
    slideIndex = x.length
  }
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    x[i].style.display = "none";
  }
  for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
    dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" w3-white", "");
  }
  x[slideIndex - 1].style.display = "block";
  dots[slideIndex - 1].className += " w3-white";
}
```

And This Is Html Side . . .

```
<div class="Image_Area_Panel">
  <div class="w3-content w3-display-container" style="max-width:800px">
    <img class="mySlides" src="http://localhost/Ajency/Public/456d6ef5aae4e33926a4c592aa5210a5--sexy-men-hot-men.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides" src="http://localhost/Ajency/Public/620b1b643b4d40bef759a386764fc630.jpg">
    <img class="mySlides" src="http://localhost/Ajency/Public/Brant-daugherty-cuff.jpg">
    <div class="w3-center w3-container w3-section w3-large w3-text-white w3-display-bottommiddle Aroos" style="width:100%">
      <div class="AreaBox">
        <div class="w3-left w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(-1)">&#10094;</div>
        <div class="w3-right w3-hover-text-khaki" onclick="plusDivs(1)">&#10095;</div>
      </div>
      <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(1)"></span>
      <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(2)"></span>
      <span class="w3-badge demo w3-border w3-transparent w3-hover-white" onclick="currentDiv(3)"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Sorry For My English Ability